# Expression Web: Frames vs. Dynamic Web Template

Tags: frames, expression-web, dwt

I am making a website that has a lot of links that do not change from page to page.  I have made similar websites before using the DWT feature of Expression Web with good results, but I still see a lot of people using frames for this kind of thing.  Is there some benefit that frames have over DWT that I am missing?  Are there any other options out there that may let me do what I want more efficiently than with the methods I have suggested?

P.S.  I also realize that frames can be used in conjunction with DWT, but thus far I have not seen a reason to... Should I be using them together for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one is biting so I'll just say that DWT is working good for me.  I guess until I see some way of development that is drastically better I will stick with DWT in Expression Studio.